# Can we ask iOS 11 related questions already?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I just noticed this iOS 11 related question [How do I enable the one-handed keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285902/how-do-i-enable-the-one-handed-keyboard) on Apple.SE, Is this allowed already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## YES

See [What happened to the "beta ban"?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/what-happened-to-the-beta-ban) for details.

Comment: Actually, it's my mistake. We lifted the beta ban last year, somehow this flew through under my radar. Will fix it right now