# Are Apple iCloud / iWork beta web apps on topic for the main site?

Tags: discussion, faq, close-reasons

Apple has 4 web apps in beta status when you log in at www.icloud.com:

- Photos
- Pages
- Numbers
- Keynote

[image: iCloud]

Since the FAQ and help section state that questions about ***Pre-release, non-publicly available beta software and software granted only under an NDA*** are off-topic, should any or all of these be on-topic while they say "beta"?

Comment: I'm pleased you brought this to a separate question—interested to see the community consensus here.

Comment: My vote is no to this since it's not NDA encumbered or "pre-release, non-publicly available" and since my overall feeling is we want to host quality questions about this iCloud / web app part of iWork.

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is that they should be acceptable (and *not* off-topic) much in [the same way Siri and Messages were](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/despite-the-general-rule-to-not-answer-questions-about-beta-products-should-we). While they are are technically "beta", I think it is largely in name only as the general public has easy access to them from the *default* panel in www.iCloud.com.

I think they also come very close to fitting into the FAQ criteria as they really aren't pre-release, and are public available.

I believe they used to be only accessible from beta.icloud.com in which case, I think it would be different, as it would more more fit into the "pre-release" clause.

Comment: Add Google betas to this exception - they can go for some time as well. Normal; betas have a projected end date and will become a release not just the developer can't be bothered to plan or decide to remove it at a whim (If a beta none can complain as they should not be using it for anything valuable)